# Patch Management

Tags: linux, windows, solaris, patch-management

I am looking for an open source patch management system that I can install locally. I would like to be able to store and search patches then download them to machines without having to search various websites.

Any recommendations?

Comment: For what systems?

Comment: I would like the server side to run on linux specifially debian, a client for it would be useful for windows, linux & solaris.

I have had a quick look around but found nothing really, I guess i need sort of an apt repository but with clients for other operations systems.

If there is none i guess i will write one myself.

Comment: related - http://serverfault.com/questions/42565/floss-server-management-and-audit-tools

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [WPKG](http://www.wpkg.org/).  It takes a bit to setup as all the packages in the repository need to have xml files instructing the system on what to do but in the end it works well.

Comment: spelling: WPKG?

Comment: oh...nice catch....fixed my typo

Comment: WPKG with wsusoffline: http://wpkg.org/index.php?title=Heise_Offline-Update

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get a win-get for windows that is like apt-get...not sure if it will help point you in the right direction

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've heard of such a program, or at least an open source one. Are you talking about for a program you're developing, or just managing updates on workstations period, or...?

I'm not sure how you'd resolve dependencies and such. The closest I've seen for things like this is Puppet for Linux and WSUS for Windows, but I have had numerous complaints about the way WSUS works and I haven't run Puppet personally.

There are some applications commercially available for Windows that will handle updating various packages but even then there's a list of what they support. Otherwise you have to create packages that get transferred to clients.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux systems you can use Spacewalk, which is basically the Red Hat Satellite Network.

Answer (score 1):

For Solaris, [PCA](http://www.par.univie.ac.at/solaris/pca/) is a script that will use your login to SunSolve to search patches based on a patch reference released from Sun (patchdiag.xref).  The script can report on patches to install, download them, and even install them.

I think it can be used to have a patch server that other machines connect to, but I haven't gotten that far with it yet!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PCA with a proxy which can have your patchset already on it.  Use that and a consistent patchdiag.xref and you can get everything the same.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian-based systems you can use [apt-cacher](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-set-up-a-repository-cache-with-apt-cacher). This tool is different from apt-cache

Answer (score 0):

Only meeting part of your critera, but Big Fix Enterprise could be an answer.

What it does is

1. Have patches for Linux & Windows
2. Allows you to write your own installation and patches
3. Patches OS, and common applications (Flash, Acrobat etc)

What it doesn't do

1. It costs, so not open source
2. The server runs on windows (unless that has recently changed)
3. The admin console runs on windows.