# Store Cron Jobs into a database

Tags: mysql, debian, database, cron

In order to build a system to maintain thousands of cron jobs on a Linux system, I'm facing the problem of being able to handle them in a scalable way. I need to use a database (I was thinking of using MySQL) for storing the jobs instead of default plaintext files.

Does anyone know if there is a module or plugin for any cron daemon that can handle this task?

Thank you in advance

Comment: someone has to ask it. Thousands of cron jobs ?!

Comment: Is this a single linux system?  Is there no way to add some kind of abstraction to your cronjobs and reduce the quantity?

Comment: Let's say hundred of rsync / curl jobs. However i can think several  different scenarios where can be useful to store cron jobs into a database instead of plain text files.

Comment: Your solution probably lies with a "Job Scheduler". There are several commercial and open source solutions, for example this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpjobscheduler/ and this http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=72&page=osource_scheduler_features_en.htm

Comment: @Not Now : i'll look into SOS-Berlin JobScheduler seems promesing, however i'd like to use native system cron if possible.

Comment: It really wouldn't be `"native system cron"` if you're modifying it to use a database backend, would it?

Comment: @eldblz Like MDMarra says, if you want to store jobs in a database, then it is not a "native cron" system. Many job schedulers can use mysql to store jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you really need for this is a job scheduler.

Please check this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software can be useful for you

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'll look into SOS-Berlin Job Scheduler seems the most promising.

Answer (score 5):

Another option, assuming you're on an OS that supports the `cron.d` directory structure, is to break your jobs into individual .cron files and manage them via the configuration management tool of your choice ([Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), for instance)

Otherwise, go with a job scheduler...

[Outgrowing cron: what's the next scheduler?](https://serverfault.com/questions/277821/outgrowing-cron-whats-the-next-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution:

https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler

Not the same as cron, but if you have temporary or sporadic jobs, Resque is a good option.

Comment: unfortunately jobs will be semi-permanent. I'd prefer to use system cron if possibile. Thank you anyway for your kind answer.